# convert array to record with map or reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, record, reduce

I have this 2d array.

```
[["hair",4560],["ringtones",33]]
```

I would like to know how to convert it to record with reduce or map:

```
[{id: {product:"hair"}, price: [454]}, {id: {product:"ringtones"}, price: [6000]}]
```

I want to use it to know in each row how col is longest.

thanks

Comment: This question has a few issues, notably that you've provided no real attempt or effort at solving this, but I question the desired result... the `id` an *object*? (of `product`?) `price` is an array with just one value? It all seems a bit strange.

Comment: Are you sure you need all those nested arrays and objects in your record? Why not just make it an array of objects?

Comment: it`s better to access item like id.product, access.price. It`s not easy to do it with the array

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have an output with this form?: `[{product: 'hair', price: 454}, {product: 'ringtones', price: 6000}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use an array map that loops through each item in the array and parses it.

```
let array = [["hair",4560],["ringtones",33]];
let arrayOfObjects = array.map(e => {
    // The structure as recommended in the comments
    // If you want the nested structure you originally were wondering about,
    // you can change the return line to match that structure
    return {product: e[0], price: e[1]};
});

/**
    Contents of the arrayOfObjects is:
    [
        { product: 'hair', price: 4560 },
        { product: 'ringtones', price: 33 }
    ]
*/
```